# Encountering React error for API call

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I'm a beginner i need some help regarding react, I am making an API call from graphql so the mutation is working perfectly on the back-end side but i cant seem to get is working on the front-end,i think its a react problem if you got know the error can you tell me where i have i made the mistake and how do i fix it. basically I'm getting a "this.props.MutationMakeProduct is not a function"
Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import {MutationMakeProduct} from '../graphqlstuff/graph';

class AddProductClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      comment: ''
    };
  }

  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.MutationMakeProduct({
      variables: {
        name: this.state.name,
        comment: this.state.comment
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form id="add-product" onSubmit={this.submitForm.bind(this)} >
        <div className="field">
          <label>Product name:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })} />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <label>Comment:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ comment: e.target.value })} />
        </div>
        <button>+</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(MutationMakeProduct)(AddProductClass);
```

Comment: when you `console.log(this.props)` what do you get back? The error is super clear, in that it's saying that this.props.MutationMakeProduct is not a function - I imagine it's not on `props`

Comment: Please post the minimum amount of code from `MutationMakeProduct` as well as the component that renders `AddProductClass`

Comment: When using the `graphql` HOC with a mutation and no `name` option configured, the default prop passed down to the component will be `mutate` not `MutationMakeProduct`, so you need to call `this.props.mutate` instead